# Highstock/Highchart scatter points in combined graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a combination chart of a scatter and columnrange.

I am having issues with the scatter plot not showing correctly.  The points seem to "stop" at a certain point after zooming in and scrolling.

https://codepen.io/moosejaw/pen/QavGgR?editors=0011

It must be related to the boost module?

I've tried enabling and disabling it.

```
boost: {
    // enabled: false // works
    enabled: true  // doesn't work
}
```

I know the boost module can handle the number of points, but I am confused on why their is a scrolling / placement issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code throws **Highcharts error 15**:  https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15 Please make sure that your data is sorted and then observe whether this issue still occurs or not.

Comment: Same Pen, just eliminated the Highcharts error 15.  Same issue.

Comment: "The points seem to "stop" at a certain point after zooming in and scrolling." Can you explain what this means. I looked at the codepen, but I don't know what the data is suppose to look like so I don't know in what way it is incorrect.

Comment: By disabling boost mode you can see.  Here is a pen disabling boost mode: https://codepen.io/moosejaw/pen/LeLryR?editors=0011

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens only when the chart is **inverted**.

It's a bug reported on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4608

---

The **workaround** here is to create inverted chart manually (which can be done via chart options and preprocessing the data):

- Swap x and y values for all points
- Set `reversed` to `true` for the y axis (when chart is inverted it's set by default: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted)
- Swap formatting and zoom options for axes
- Handle the format of tooltip (`tooltip.formatter` may be useful)

Comment: Can you adjust the codepen so I can see?  Thank you.

Comment: The chart has to be inverted because of the column range.

Comment: You can mimic column range series using polygon: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/amf911cx/